# How to get the information of Diagnostic logs from Azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-diagnostics, azure-monitoring

If anyone is working with Azure and could help me, I would appreciate it.
I am trying to trigger an action every time the creation of a file is logged in an azure data lake path and I need the following to be true:

- It has to be in real time
- Should report which file is the one created, at what time and which user

I have tried to do it with the ADL diagnostic logs by routing them to an eventhub but the events arrive normally after 3 minutes, I have also tried to do it with Log Analytics and it takes longer for the information to arrive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, you can make use of [`Azure Event Grids`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/event-grid/) where an event will be fired as soon as a file is created. You can invoke an Azure Function to consume that event and do further processing.

You can find more information about it in the following links:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/event-driven-analytics-with-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json